# Passing variable from jquery to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, variables

i want to pass a variable from jquery to php but my code doesnt work .I tried very hard but no luck . When i click the button nothing happens.plz help thank you

one more thing i tried this without passing variable and i use only echo command then it works but when i pass variable nothing happens

```
<html>
    <head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
   $("button").click(function(){
    var var_data = 5;
     $.ajax({
        url: "myscript.php",
        data: { var_php_data: var_data },
        success: function(data) {
            // do something;
                              alert(data);
        }
 });
  });
   </script>
  </head>
  <body>


<button>Change Content</button>

   </body>
  </html>
```

myscript.php contains the following code

```
    <?php
  echo $_GET['var_php_data'];
   ?>
```

Comment: The next time you run into stuff like this, use a debugger or put a few `console.log` calls into your code to see what it's doing. You would've seen that the event handler isn't even being called, and the whole "passing variable from jquery to php" thing isn't even a part of your problem.

Answer (score 5):

Try wrapping your script in a document ready handler. Also you have a trailing comma (`,`) after the success callback that you should remove. Also you should use a `,` instead of `;` after the `data` parameter. Specifying the HTTP verb for your AJAX request might also be useful:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('button').click(function() {
                var var_data = 5;
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'myscript.php',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: { var_PHP_data: var_data },
                    success: function(data) {
                        // do something;
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button>Change Content</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The reason you need to wrap your click registration in a document ready handler is because you put your script inside the `<head>` section of your markup and the button hasn't yet been loaded by the browser when you attempt to subscribe to its click handler.

Comment: was gonna ask why we need to wrap document.ready() to handle button clicks  :)

Comment: @Krish, you need to do this if your script is defined before the actual DOM element that you are subscribing for some events to. If you put your script at the end just before the closing `</body>` tag you don't need it.

Comment: @user1189906, do you see some errors in your javascript console? For example you could use FireBug or some developer toolbar built-in your browser to see if there might be some other errors. You can also see if the actual AJAX request is being sent when you click on the button. You can see the exact request and response from the server. Also make sure that the path to jquery.js is correct and it exists on your server.

Comment: Does  http://{your_host}>/myscript.php?var_PHP_data=echoText returns some result? You don't need $(document).ready in this particular case. Before you click on the button everything is loaded for sure

Comment: Is the AJAX request being sent? Can you see it in the console or the Net tab? Is the path to jquery.js correct?

Comment: i tried this without passing variable and i use only echo command then it works but when i pass variable nothing happens

Comment: So what happens when you directly type  `http://{your_host}/myscript.php?var_PHP_data=123` in the address bar of your browser?

Comment: yes every thing is correct the problem comes only when i pass variable to the php

Comment: And what's the problem? You get an error message from your PHP script? What kind of error message are you getting?

Comment: this massg comes when i visit that link-PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  var_php_data in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myscript.php on line 2

Comment: @user1189906, there you go. Now fix the errors in your PHP script. In your question you have shown `myscript.php` whereas the error seem to be pointing to `myscript1.php`.

Comment: var_php_data != var_PHP_data? I'm not familiar with php

Comment: @user1189906, I am not a magician and I cannot read your mind. How on earth do you expect us helping you without showing your code? The code you have shown with the `echo` should work fine. But the error you are getting seems to be pointing to some `var_php_data` variable inside `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myscript.php`.

Comment: check for the name of variable var_php_data. It should be the same on front and in your php script.

Comment: bro sorry but my all code is written above , sorry that i am irritating you ,i am newbie sorry

Comment: echo $_GET['var_php_data'];   in this line its sowing the error,i have only one line in my myscript.php

Comment: i checked it variable is the same

Comment: i also tried other variable with $.post method but there also problem comes when i pass the variable

Comment: replace your code to &lt;?php phpinfo() ?&gt;. Did you get info page? If it success, try &lt;?php  echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ?&gt;. Does it work?

Comment: which code i have to reply i m a newbie. thanx very much for replying

Comment: http://localhost/myscript.php?var_php_data=5 i tried this and page shows no error

Comment: @user1189906, ok now try: `data: { var_php_data: var_data }` on the client.

Comment: Well, I don't know what to say. Maybe you should get a book about PHP or read some getting started tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Firebug (Firexox plugin), or user something similar for your browser to see real HTTP request and response. If you will post them here it will be more simple to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Track request in FireBug. You can find by FB did request success (200) as well as date send by request.
Also, try http://{your_host}>/myscript.php?var_PHP_data=echoText

Addition:
Darin Dimitrov described the problem right way